# Prevent actions if validation fails on blur event

Tags: javascript, jquery

On blur of an input field I want to run a validator. If validation fails I need to set focus back in to the field and cancel out the next intended operation.

I am able to achieve the first part, to set the focus back into the field, but the next operations (button click, link click) are also executing. I need help in restricting actions if validation fails in blur.

Following is the code snippet replicating this behavior. Focus on the field and then try to click on the link/button. Their callbacks are getting executed, which I need to restricted if there is an error on `blur` event handler of the input field.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.form-control').blur(function(e) {
    var $this = jQuery(this),
      hasError = true;

    if (hasError) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $this.focus();
      }, 0);
      return false;
    }
  });

  $('.link').click(function(e) {
    console.log('link clicked');
  });

  $('.button').click(function(e) {
    console.log('button clicked');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" />
  <br/><br/>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="link">Link</a>
  <br/><br/>
  <button class="button">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Move the `hasError` bool out of the on blur function and make it a global variable that the `click` events can check against before doing their actions.

Comment: Actions include header navigation, left navigation and many many other actions on the page (not all having the click handler function)... putting a check on all of that on this variable will be altogether a bigger task.

Comment: I am unable to think of a way to do this without using a flag to check against sorry

Comment: You will have to use a flag and check it in every action. This also sounds like really bad UX. You're not letting the user do *anything* if there's an error in the form?

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `pointer-events`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.form-control').blur(function(e) {
     var $this = jQuery(this), 
     hasError = $this.val().trim()== ''?true:false;
     
     if(hasError) {
       setTimeout(function() {
         $this.focus();
       }, 0);
       $('.link, .button').css('pointer-events','none');
     }
     else $('.link, .button').css('pointer-events','');
   });
  
  $('.link').click(function(e) {
     console.log('link clicked');
   });
  
  $('.button').click(function(e) {
       console.log('button clicked');
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
  
  <div class="container">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" />
    
    <br/><br/>
    
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="link">Link</a>
    
    <br/><br/>
    
    <button class="button"> Submit</button>
    
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As I said, it's not just about two or three actions on the page. There is header navigation, left navigation (multi-level), multiple actions on the page... all those actions have to be prevented. Toggling a class to all those elements doesn't seems to be more generic solution for this scenario.

Comment: Nice solution. This is about as generic and easily maintainable as you're going to get.